# Create obround from a circle using transform in css or some other performant way

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an obround from a circle using `transform: scaleX(2)` but it results in ellipse. I get the obround by increasing the width but the transition becomes janky in my application. Is there a performant way to do this transition. I am attaching a sandbox link here to show the behaviour.

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-leavitt-r6tcw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes but not with a single element, since you need different transformations for the body of your shape (which you can think of as a rect) and the two circles.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('button').click(() => {
    $('.shape').toggleClass('expanded');
  });
});
```

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -12px;
  background: red;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background: blue;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.rect {
  width: 1px;
  height: 24px;
  background: blue;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.shape.expanded .circle.left {
  transform: translateX(-32px);
}

.shape.expanded .circle.right {
  transform: translateX(32px);
}

.shape.expanded .rect {
  transform: scaleX(64);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape">
  <div class="circle left"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="circle right"></div>
</div>

<button>toggle</button>
```

Comment: This is definitely a good solution but I do not have more than one elements as I am overriding the css of an external library for carousels.

Comment: @sudheersingh so perhaps you should try the same thing with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements on your single element, though you would also need to scale `::before` and `::after` down at the same rate that you are scaling the whole thing up.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought initially but its already being used.

Comment: @sudheersingh I really cannot think of any other transition-based solution, is it possible for you to inject the additional elements using javascript? though I do realize that that might not be worth the effort for just having a smoother animation.

Comment: and that wont even give me smoother animation. Width change would be more performant. Guess I will settle with the width based janky animation. lol.

Comment: @sudheersingh how so? generally transition animations should be much more performant than width change animations, as the later would require recalculation of layout while the former won't, so I'm curious on how in your case they would not give you smoother animations. though I do feel you and I would also either settle for the width animation or even scrap the animation if performance on mobile is key totally instead of going with dom injection.

Comment: Sure, we would gain from the transition but dom injection would also force layout plus time for node insertion. It would be a net loss.

Comment: @sudheersingh well the dom insertion (and the ensuing layout recalculation) would actually happen once, however the performance gain on animating transitions would relate to every frame (i.e. if you were to animate width, recalculation would occur on every frame).